# if statement with a search text condition in a tuple

Tags: if-statement, erlang, tuples

I need to write in erlang an if statement with the condition to search this test "tele/folin-house-s1/SENSOR" in the tuples that I recevie.
Below I insert the tuples I'm receiving:

```
{message,<<0,5,128,208,182,250,162,9,244,64,0,0,105,198,0,0>>,
     1,<<"DVES_0DBFDB">>,
     #{dup => false,retain => true},
     #{username => undefined},
     <<"tele/folin-house-s1/LWT">>,<<"Offline">>,
     {1549,8794,985040}}.
{message,<<0,5,128,208,182,250,162,9,244,64,0,0,105,198,0,0>>,
     1,<<"DVES_0DBFDB">>,
     #{dup => false,retain => true},
     #{username => undefined},
     <<"tele/folin-house-s1/LWT">>,<<"Offline">>,
     {1549,8794,985040}}.
{message,undefined,0,<<"733f0bfd-0741-4e55-bd14-ba10a156165f1549007325254">>,
     #{dup => false,retain => false},
     #{username => undefined},
     <<"tele/folin-house-s1/SENSOR">>,
     <<"{\"Time\":\"2018-12-18T22:37:00\",\"BME680\":{\"Temperature\":21.3,\"Humidity\":38.1,\"Pressure\":1021.4,\"Gas\":308.19},\"TempUnit\":\"C\"}">>,
     {1549,8796,895335}}.
{message,undefined,0,<<"733f0bfd-0741-4e55-bd14-ba10a156165f1549007325254">>,
     #{dup => false,retain => false},
     #{username => undefined},
     <<"tele/folin-house-s1/SENSOR">>,
     <<"{\"Time\":\"2018-12-18T22:37:00\",\"BME680\":{\"Temperature\":21.3,\"Humidity\":38.1,\"Pressure\":1021.4,\"Gas\":308.19},\"TempUnit\":\"C\"}">>,
     {1549,8803,302986}}.
```

I would to filter with an if statement only the tuple like this one:

```
{message,undefined,0,<<"733f0bfd-0741-4e55-bd14-ba10a156165f1549007325254">>,
     #{dup => false,retain => false},
     #{username => undefined},
     <<"tele/folin-house-s1/SENSOR">>,
     <<"{\"Time\":\"2018-12-18T22:37:00\",\"BME680\":{\"Temperature\":21.3,\"Humidity\":38.1,\"Pressure\":1021.4,\"Gas\":308.19},\"TempUnit\":\"C\"}">>,
     {1549,8803,302986}}.
```

that contains "tele/folin-house-s1/SENSOR". I don't know erlang coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might it would be better to use case clause

in that case you need to pass received tuple through the function

here is the function example :

```
message({message,_, _,_, _, _, <<"tele/folin-house-s1/LWT">>,_, _}) ->
  do_something();
message(_Tuple) -> skip.
```

here is the example with 'case' statement:

```
message({message,_, _,_, _, _, Condition,_, _}) ->
  case Condition of
    <<"tele/folin-house-s1/LWT">> -> do_something();
    _Any -> skip
  end.
```

here is the example with 'if' statement:

```
message({message,_, _,_, _, _, Condition,_, _}) ->
  if
    Condition =:= <<"tele/folin-house-s1/LWT">> ->
      do_something();
    true ->
      skip
  end.
```